# Field vs Property

Tags: json

On
[this page](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual)
it mentions JSON fields and properties

```
specify a particular field or property to examine
```

What is the difference between a JSON field and property?

Comment: This is pretty good question. It confused my as well when some people use word "field" and others use "property"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Nothing.

When talking about JSON (as opposed to C# or C++), both terms mean the same thing.

He mentions both terms to clarify for people who are only familiar with one of them.

Comment: And no other answers? I always expect to see some philosophy around questions like this.. But hey, if nobody is complaining, fine enough for me :)

Comment: I looked it up and RFC 7159 https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159 uses the term `member` in the case of JSON. So we've got a third term here :)

Comment: http://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html#properties
is naming "properties".

Comment: FYI, RFC7159 was obsoleted by https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8259 - but the result is the same.

Comment: Looking at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON they're called: "attributes".